# WEP access point with hostapd

Tags: hostapd

I'm trying to set up a WEP access point for old hardware.

Here's my `hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlx08beac0a6c1d
country_code=UK
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=0
hw_mode=g
channel=4

wmm_enabled=1

ssid=banana
wpa=0
auth_algs=2
macaddr_acl=1
accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept

wep_default_key=0
wep_key0="01234567890123"

wep_key_len_broadcast=13
wep_key_len_unicast=13
wep_rekey_period=300
```

But nothing can connect.
Both wpa and completely open work fine, but not this.
What have I got wrong?